# Tools for geospatial data visualization with custom 3D models

Tags: data-visualization, webgl, mapbox, geospatial, kepler.gl

I need a tool that does geospatial data visualization, but which will also allow me to import, or to create custom 3D models (e.g. to import .gltf files).

Kepler.gl seems a great choice for geospatial data visualization, yet I couldn't find the way to import certain .gltf file and I am not sure this is even possible in kepler.gl.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored the latest version of [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox)?? It enables you to add as many models and 3D layers as you want on top of Mapbox using their support for 3D objects through `CustomLayerInterface` with only a few lines of code

```
    map.on('style.load', function () {
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'custom_layer',
            type: 'custom',
            renderingMode: '3d',
            onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

                window.tb = new Threebox(
                    map,
                    mbxContext,
                    { defaultLights: true }
                );

                var options = {
                    obj: '/3D/soldier/soldier.glb',
                    type: 'gltf',
                    scale: 1,
                    units: 'meters',
                    rotation: { x: 90, y: 0, z: 0 } //default rotation
                }

                tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                    soldier = model.setCoords(origin);
                    tb.add(soldier);
                })

            },
            render: function (gl, matrix) {
                tb.update();
            }
        });
    })
```

And you can do much more...
**- 3D models built-in and custom animations**

[image: 3D models built-in and custom animations]

**- Full raycast support MouseOver/Mouseout, Selected, Drag&Drop, Drag&Rotate, Wireframe**

[image: MouseOver/Mouseout, Selected, Drag&Drop, Drag&Rotate, Wireframe]

**- CSS2D Tooltips and Labels that consider altitude**

[image: CSS2D Tooltips and Labels that consider altitude]

**- Three.js and Mapbox cameras sync with depth adjustment**

[image: Three.js and Mapbox cameras sync with depth adjustment]

**- Include geolocated models of monuments with sunlight & shadows build-in support**

[image: Eiffel tower gif]

**- Optimized to load thousands of 3D objects**

[image: Performance]

Comment: Vow, this looks really interesting! It might be the answer so I am willing to give it a try. So this is free (MIT license, as I can see)?

Comment: MIT yes, you have to keep license. If it solved your question, whenever you have time to test it, please mark it as Answer Accepted

Comment: Surely I will, once I test it and see if it fits my needs. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you have any issue, specially any bug, don't hesitate to open an issue in the github repo